# Accessing a Novell share on Trusty Tahr?

Tags: 14.04, mount, novell-netware

After upgrading my pc to the current LTS release 14. 04, I found that I can't access novell shares using ncpfs any more. It seems that the ncp-related packages (libncp and so on) have been present in the 14.04 repos, but got removed: (see [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ncpfs), [ubuntuupdates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/libncp) and [Debian Bug #712779](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712779)).

Is there still any way to install the ncp-related components?

Are there any other tools to access or even mount a novell share from a 14.04 system?

EDIT: Oddly enough, `ncpfs` and `libncp` are still available in the current LTS Version of Mint (Mint 17 "Qiana").

Comment: Any reasons for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ncp-related packages [are still part of the older releases](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/libncp), they're available after adding Saucy (`universe`!) as additional package source. Now, one can install them as usual (Version 2.2.6-9ubuntu1 seems to work fine with 14.04).

You can do this by opening Software & Updates in Ubuntu and enabling the `universe` repository, or you can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
# ncpfs
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is it removed ?!

I think many people use it cause there is no Novell Client for Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ncpfs
```

Comment: Official link down, you can still download it here:    http://ftp.ksu.edu.tw/FTP/Linux/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncpfs/