# How to install libncp-dev on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

OS is Ubuntu 14.04.
I got a dependency issue where the dependency needed is `libncp-dev`.

How to resolve this dependency issue on Ubuntu 14.04?

EDIT: apt cant find the package

```
E: Unable to locate package libncp-dev
```

Comment: What would be if you just run `sudo apt-get install libncp-dev`?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libncp-dev

Comment: i took the "libncp 2.2.6-9ubuntu1 (amd64 binary) in ubuntu trusty" libncp_2.2.6-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb & "libncp-dev 2.2.6-9ubuntu1 (amd64 binary) in ubuntu trusty" libncp-dev_2.2.6-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libncp-dev
```

Worked for me

EDIT: add-apt-repository will add the saucy repsitory for universe and multiverse to your /etc/apt/sources.list file which is where the libncp-dev package currently resides.

Originally From: "[Accessing a Novell share on Trusty Tahr?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481705/accessing-a-novell-share-on-trusty-tahr)"

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! To improve this answer it may be helpful to explain the commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Debian package of `libncp-dev` from Debian repository.

Example for amd64:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/ncpfs/libncp-dev_2.2.6-9_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libncp-dev_2.2.6-9_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Other architectures can be found here: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libncp-dev

Comment: he is using ubuntu not debian, it is inadvisable to mix distros.

Comment: Yes I know, but It's the another solution that works in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but:

Neither Debian (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libncp-dev) nor Ubuntu (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libncp-dev&searchon=names&section=all) have supported releases with libncp-dev.